# Does Unity3d support Non blocking network IO?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Are there networking libraries in Unity3d which support NIO? I would like to avoid keeping CPU threads busy waiting on network calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try the [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class.

Or, you can simply use C# [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.socket). Note that for using sockets for iOS or Android you'll need a pro license for both of them.